# I have added a randomized aodv to ns 2.35 and I'm getting the following error.I have added all the .h and .cc file in their respective places

Tags: tcl, ns2

trace/cmu-trace.cc:971:40: error: ‘acces’ is not a member of ‘hdr_raodv’
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1017:14: error: ‘RAODVTYPE_RREP’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [trace/cmu-trace.o] Error 1
 Please do help me.

Comment: Please share some of your code so people can see what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks @Knelis .I have added here what I have done.Please suggest me if anything to be modified.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

@Knelis :

The code is "RAODV , Reverse AODV" ,,,  r-aodv.zip by @elmurod

http://elmurod.net/sfiles/r-aodv.zip ,,, for ns-2.28 !

So it's quite straightforward that the year 2006 code can fail in ns-2.35.

About »RAODV , Reverse AODV« : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/OOBlVuMYiUQ

.